# Typedef "AVMediaType cannot be referenced with enum spcecifier"

Tags: typedef

After updating to Mac High OS X Sierra in my Xcode9, my project has a lot of compile errors, as title describes. The AVMediaType are referenced nine times and I can't change it. These errors are in the built in avformat.h and avcodec.h files.

What should I do to change this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave an example of the code that is producing errors and what you've done so far to try and alleviate them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the library files such as ffmpeg and change the permissions in 'GetInfo' give yourself write and read access. Open the files in ffmpeg avutil.h in another program (I used Sublime) and edit your file as needed. Do this for all your ffmpeg files that use the AVMediaType that are giving you the name error.